# I'm confused when to use Bernoulli's equation and continuity momentum equation

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation

[Conflicts between Bernoulli's Equation and Momentum Conservation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220084/)

1). Is this equation compatible with any case? And how?

[image]

2). Isn't $\rho u$ from the derivation of the Bernoulli's equation a constant value as of the continuity momentum equation?

[image]

3). Isn't the mass flow rate of both compressible and incompressible flow remain constant that we can use only the continuity momentum equation?

Comment: Please avoid scan linking long tracts of text/formulas: they aren't searchable by SEs. Instead summarise and use Latex rendering of formulas.

Answer (score 0):

The momentum equation
$$\rho_1u_1^2 + p_1 = \rho_2u_2^2 + p_2$$
is applicable to a one-dimensional, steady, inviscid, compressible or incompressible flow.

Bernoulli's equation
$$p_1+\frac{\rho v_1^2}{2} = p_2+\frac{\rho v_2^2}{2}$$
is applicable to a steady, incompressible, isentropic (inviscid + adiabatic) flow.

Comment: Bernoulli for compressible flow is $v^2/2+h= constant$, where $h$ is the specific enthlapy.  This implies that the $\rho v^2+p=constat$ only holds when both $p$ and $v^2$ are constants, so the equation is not actually much use.

Comment: @mikestone How did you arrive at that conclusion? The momentum equation definitely holds for cases where all three quantities $\rho$, $u$ and $p$ are variable, and it is applied to solve problems such as shock waves and gaseous detonations.

Comment: Ah yes!  You are right I was thinking of things like de Laval flow and  using isentropic $PV^\gamma=const$ to get my conclusion ---  but shocks and detonations  are not isentropic. Bernoulli still holds in the form that $1/2 v^2 + h=const$, but $PV^\gamma \ne const.$.